# Can Apache cxf rest client proxy work with reactive interface

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cxf, feign

Let's suppose that I have an interface that describes another rest service. It looks like this:

```
@Produces("application/json")
public interface PetApi {


    @GET
    @Path("pet/{petId}")
    String getPet(@PathParam("petId") Long petId);
}
```

and it works fine when I call it:

```
    private static void testPet() {
        PetApi petApi = JAXRSClientFactory.create("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2", PetApi.class);

        String petDescr = petApi.getPet(1L);
        System.out.println(petDescr);
    }
```

Now I want to improve this code for work into the reactive flow. Can apache CXF generate proxies for work into reactive code? In this manner calling code will look like this:

```
    private static void testPet() {
        PetApi petApi = JAXRSClientFactory.create("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2", PetApi.class);

        CompletionStage<String> petDescrCs = petApi.getPet(1L);
        petDescrCs.thenAccept(System.out::println);
    }
```

and interface for external rest service is:

```
@Produces("application/json")
public interface PetApi {


    @GET
    @Path("pet/{petId}")
    CompletionStage<String> getPet(@PathParam("petId") Long petId);
}
```

The upstairs code not work. It is my opinion how it might be. My question is there any way to implement functionality like this

Or maybe someone knows another framework that can build reactive rest proxies like this

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign starting from version 10.8 can do reactive calls.

see https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#async-execution-via-completablefuture.

Applied to the code from the question...

dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>11.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Interface:

```
@Produces("application/json")
public interface PetApi {


    // Reactive method. Work only with CompletableFuture(not work with CompletionStage)
    @GET
    @Path("pet/{petId}")
    CompletableFuture<String> getPetCs(@PathParam("petId") Long petId);

    // Non reactive method
    @GET
    @Path("pet/{petId}")
    String getPet(@PathParam("petId") Long petId);
}
```

call example:

```
    private static void reactiveTest() {
        PetApi petApi = AsyncFeign.asyncBuilder()
                .contract(new JAXRSContract()) // JAX-RS contract for fegin
                .target(PetApi.class, "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2");
        CompletionStage<String> petDescrCs = petApi.getPetCs(1L);
        petDescrCs.thenAccept(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void noneReactiveTest() {
        PetApi petApi = AsyncFeign.asyncBuilder()
                .contract(new JAXRSContract()) // JAX-RS contract for fegin
                .target(PetApi.class, "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2");
        String petDescr = petApi.getPet(1L);
        System.out.println(petDescr);
    }
```